# Including a clickable svg file in an HTML document

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a formation homework to do, consisting in working with a "WORLD" database with cities, countries and languages tables. I want to point out that I don't need this to validate the module, it's just personnal enhancement of my project. I can do (and have already done) it with a classic map area, it's just that I want to work some more interesting options.

One of the items is making a clickable map of the world to generate accesses to the database. Well, I followed [this link](https://thenewcode.com/696/Using-SVG-as-an-Alternative-To-Imagemaps) to do this with [this Wikipedia file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/BlankMap-World.svg). There is in this file everything I need... Except that I don't know how to insert it to have full control of its features.

It is said in the tutorial that I should include the file inside a div, like this :

```
<div class="svg-container">
    <?php echo file_get_contents("World Map.svg"); ?>
</div>
```

this works fine. Then I have to include in the svg file a "class" statment :

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     width="2754" height="1398" class="svg-content">
```

Problem is, when I do this, the image disapear :-(

I have tried a huge number of methods, for example including the file in an img (don't have access to the intern features of the svg, for example the links I would add), an object (image is all black, and the css part is typeset above the image...), nothing works, and the image itself doesn't scale correctely...

Could anyone help me use the map in my project ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you include the class to your SVG?

Comment: I don't understand the question... There are styles in the svg file, and I put a ".svg-content" in my style.css file loaded in the page with the map... If that is what you ask.

Comment: My question is how are you adding the class to the svg? is it in the original svg file or you add it after rendering the svg file content? P.S. I recommend not using spaces and make all letters in small form

Comment: I solved my problem. It seemed there was a problem with my CSS file.Everything works nicely now (except for one or two svg features I'll have to dig into later).
Thanks for your help and your time :-)

Comment: Great, you are welcome 